How do you find examples of how a person from a particular place and time period would speak?
Is there a good resource for finding how someone from a certain time period would sound? In my particular example I'm thinking early 1900s Kansas, but I'm also looking for how to do this generally.

Try and find (ordered from formal to vernacular):

Books from the language and area, both fiction and non-fiction. This will give you the vocabulary of that time and place and the more formal styles of writing and speaking.
Searching for "writers from kansas" on Google returned several lists (e.g. on Wikipedia). Searching for "kansas literature" found me an overview with many examples on the website of Washburn University. You'll have to refine your search until you find (enough of) what you need.

Private journals, court documents (with witness accounts), letters, and other non- or less-formal writing. There are some published collections, but you may have to dig into archives.
Searching for "english kansas 19th century" on Google Scholar brought me Adeline & Julia: Growing Up in Michigan and on the Kansas Frontier: Diaries from 19th-Century America as the first result. The Washburn University overview mentioned above also lists some letters and journals in the "Memoirs" section.

Records of everyday speech. Ethnologists, linguists, folklorists, in earlier times Christian missonaries, surveyors, and other officials have been collecting oral narratives and linguistic examples since early modern times. Since some of these records are spread over all kinds of non-linguistic materials, it might require a lot of original research and necessitate historic and linguistic expertise to find them.

If you are lucky, linguists have published research papers or monographs on the language of the time and place you are interested in. Use Google Scholar and similar databases to search for these.
I recommend to do your research in a university library. Some scientific databases and many of the publications you will find require paid registration, but you can often access some of them for free from within a university library.
University libraries often have a list of databases somewhere on their websites. There are specialized linguistic bibliographic databases such as https://bibliographies.brill.com/LBO/ or https://www.blldb-online.de. I tried searching for "Kansas" in these two and each returned a few results about variants of German and Spanish spoken in Kansas. Here is an example for a database of linguisitic databases: https://www.linguistik.de/en/search/database-directory/, and here is the database directory of the University of Kansas: https://lib.ku.edu/articles-and-databases.



Generally, before you begin your research, you should consider whether writing in an archaic variant of your language is actually what you want to do.
Ask yourself:

Can my readers understand speech from the time period in which my story takes place? Since you write for 21st century English speakers, you may want to render speech from historic persons in contemporary 21st century English so your readers can understand what you write, at least in popular fiction. For example, if your story is set among 19th century Kansas Mennonites, they will be speaking German amongst themselves, which most of your readers will not understand, I assume.
Does the level of linguistic veracity correspond to how much research you have put into researching and depicting other elements of your story (such as clothing, architecture, living conditions, social conventions, politics, food etc.)? If you write a Western Romance without any historical accuracy, you don't need your characters to speak in correct 19th century Kansas English either. It may be enough to avoid words that came into the language later.
How prominently will what you want to research appear in your writing? As a professional writer, you don't only want to write well, you'll also want to write efficiently. It's not really economical to spend weeks on researching a language that is spoken in only a handful of sentences in your novel.


Oh my gosh, you're a gem. Thank you!
